# What is the limit of a web developer responsibilities?

Tags: career-development

I'm learning to be a web developer, I want to the most information possible in a limited time, practice some projects then venture into the real work.

You know how many there are of languages, frames, standards...etc one should learn. While in the first phase, I found a lot of learning material that is at the limit of the development and at the beginning of other aspects such as administration. The more I dig the more of it appear and I seem to deviate of my purpose of learning web development. I don't know where to stop?

Is there anybody who can tell me the accepted competences of a person to apply as a web developer with emphasis of the non-development abilities?

I know there may not be a clear cut answer but at least a starting point

Comment: This competences would vary greatly between different jobs and companies. Are you worried you are not focusing what you learn enough to be an effective web developer? Developing in general is an holistic process; you have to be keen on several things and steps in the product life cycle to be an effective developer.

Comment: I don't think this is one we can really answer for you - individiual employers will have their own ideas of what duties a role encompasses. Probably your best bet would be to have a read of various job adverts for entry-level web development roles and see what skills the majority list.

Comment: You realize what you're asking right?  You want to be a Web "Developer" but not actually do development?  20 years ago, you could get a job doing just HTML/CSS, but these days there are so much easier ways to create a site, very few companies hire for just these basic skills anymore.  You should concentrate on a specific framework, and run with it until you "get it".  I suggest starting with BootStrap, as you can quickly create usable sites without needing to fully understand what is going on under the hood.

Comment: @motosubatsu, great idea, but most companies, list their requirements like this : web developer : PHP, MySQL, JavaScript,...autonomous, good communication skills, ... just general stuff, then you end doing everything what a computer relates to. But still you're idea is worth trying.

Comment: @raterus, sorry I didn't make myself clear, look at the example when you're learning, MySQL that is nearly a must for web development, it is a huge topic though, you can spend years before fully mastering it, but some aspects of it can be more related to database administration than to web development, that were my question was : should learn all MySQL aspects or just web development specific.

Comment: My suggestion in this order, learn what you need, what you can learn, what you want to learn. Each job, department, project, company, industry and technology is going to change. When someone asks you for an estimate, it's really a guess, same as all the answers to your questions.

Comment: The limit of your responsibility is whatever your employer pays you to do. I am not sure I understand your goal here.

Comment: Define "administration". Is this administration regarding you/your job, or more widely spread?

Comment: @EdwinLambregts, administration in genereal.

Answer (score 5):

You're putting the cart before the horse.  I'm 20 years into a web development career now, and I came in my first position with no experience developing websites.  Everything I learned, I learned because there was a business requirement, and I stepped up to meet that requirement using a technology I learned on the job.

I commend you for getting some experience before you're hired, but know that employers are going to want to see real-world experience to really want to hire you.  Saying you read a book, or played around with this technology doesn't go far.

Even if you have to donate time, find someone, somewhere that you can help learn web development from.  Are there charity organizations around you could help setup a simple site, for free.  You're looking for experience, *real experience*.

Get some real experience, then concentrate on getting your **foot in the door** for an entry-level position.  Let your career grow and take off from there.

Comment: This is the correct answer, for my money.  There's **way** too much stuff out there, and it changes **way** too quickly, for you to learn it all up front.  Employers in the industry know this, too.  OP mentioned MySQL in another comment: You don't need to know *everything* about SQL before you start.  As long as you can piece together some simple queries, you can figure out the more complex stuff as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, developer need to be eclectic person.
There is no limitation of what you could face during your career.

As a starting point thou, perhaps, try go through available positions at companies with large teams of developers and concentrate on team development strategies and tools.
This will give you potential entry point to become part of their team.

From there, there is no limit to what you can learn and get proficient with.

SideNote warning:
As beginner, you may not want to go to small companies (1-2 dev staff), as there you have higher chance of burnout due to wide range of knowledge you may need in very short period of time.

Good luck and dont get discouraged, programming is everything ;)

Answer (score 1):

Learn JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and Git (a common version control system) well. There are many frameworks out there and hopping from one to another without learning enough about any of them is a waste of time.

After you're building websites easily with those skills (I recommend doing so on GitHub Pages to have a public facing profile), look at the frameworks that are most popular in the job postings that you're interested in and pick ONE. Learn it well.

Don't worry, in a few years, you'll pick up a lot more through your job, side projects, and continuing education.

Don't lie on your resume. Only put down which skills you have a solid understanding of.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript, HTML, CSS, are clearly not administrative tasks, they are front-end web developers tasks. but the distinction becomes fuzzier when trying to apply as a full stack web developer.

Comment: Full stack developer isn't really an entry-level position. Yes, there are bootcamps that advertise that you'll be a full stack developer in a matter of months under their education, but I wouldn't recommend trying to emulate that approach to starting a career.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're concentrating too much on technologies and not enough on fundamentals. The limitation of web development ends with whatever your company is willing to allow you to do. Some places are more slack while others are not. You'll want to find a company that allows you to use a wide range of tools and upon learning those tools you can jump to another job that might expand a little on that.

Don't go crazy reading into every technology. I had a co worker who loved reading up on the latest craze, but one time was tasked with implementing something he read and he backed out because he didn't really know anything beyond what he read.